# fix cut tile javascript

Tags: title, cut

i have code cut tile:
TITL1 - TITLE2 [XXX]

```
   var Enumber1 = new Array();
           $("#id").each(function(i){
           var text = $(this).text();
           if(text.indexOf('[') != -1 || text.indexOf(']') != -1){
             var Ntext1      = text.split('[')[0];
             Enumber1[i] = text.split('[')[1].split(']')[0];
             $(this).text(Ntext1);
           }
         });
         $("#id").each(function(i){         
           $(this).fadeIn("slow");
           if(Enumber1[i] != undefined){
             $(this).text(Enumber1[i]);
           }else{
             $(this).css('N/A');
           }


    });
```

- TITLE1 -TITL2  >>> div class="title"
- [XXX] >>> div class="cut"
  DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/bro69zvb/

Help me fix it

- TILE1 in >>> in
- 2.TITLE >>> in
- XXX >>> in

thanks!!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bro69zvb/ thanks bro! :)

Comment: I want it divided into 3 parts

Comment: 1:title    2:title2     3:xxx

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: Please demo in  jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your script area:

```
var Enumber1 = new Array();
var longOfArray=0;
$(".title").each(function(i){
  var text = $(this).text();  
  var res = text.replace(" -","");
  res =  res.split(" ");
  //res contains "title1,title2,[xxx]"  
    longOfArray = res.length;
  //lenght of this array is 3
  Enumber1 = res;
  //stored into your array
  $(".title").html("");
  //emptied first title
  });


  $(".cut").each(function(i){   
  //iterate through array to fill .cut div
  for(i=0;i<longOfArray; i++){

    if(Enumber1[i].indexOf("[")!=-1){            
  //remove first lash [
             var firstLash = Enumber1[i].indexOf("[");     
       Enumber1[i] = Enumber1[i].substring(firstLash+1);
    } 
    if(Enumber1[i].indexOf("]")!=-1){  
     //remove last lash ]
       var lastLash = Enumber1[i].indexOf("]");
       Enumber1[i] = Enumber1[i].substring(0,lastLash);
    } 

   $(".cut").append("<p>"+(i+1)+" "+Enumber1[i]+"</p>");
  } 
  });
```

Being your html like this:

```
<div class="title">
Title1 - Title2 [XXX]
</div>
<div class="cut">
</div>
```

Comment: You could do removing of [] in one function, i made two in the assumption that not always will be [xxx] that could be "[ccc" or "yyy]"

Comment: @Zac please close question and mark answer valid, if it is.

Comment: Ah but i want 3 components in 3 id

Comment: <div class="title"/> cut >>>> <div class="title2"> <div class="xxx"> Help me last time. thank you very much